# vstudio 2013 won't open (or start new) winforms projects

Tags: mysql, winforms, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 community. Two days ago I was using it with a winforms project without problems, and now I can not open winforms projects, and the templates for start new winforms projects just disappeared.

There have not been any changes in my computer except that i installed MYSQL. Could that be the problem? I hope not, since i want to use it.

I've read various similar questions here at stackoverflow searching for a solution, and update microsoft azure following some answer i can't find right now, without any changes.

... help? :P

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The thing is that I don't get error dialog anymore, I only got one the first time and I didn't remember to note it down :( Now the templates just are not there, and when i try to open an existing project i get this: http://es.tinypic.com/r/eal2d2/9

Comment: I've just searched the webs i've seen today and this is the error Visual Studio threw the first time: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charles_sterling/archive/2015/06/17/this-version-of-visual-studio-is-unable-to-open-the-following-projects-deployproj.aspx  . That's why I installed azure after MYSQL

Comment: It's solved, i reinstalled visual studio and now it's working again.